# Перевод "work item" в компьютерной терминологии

Tags: перевод

Какой перевод с Англ. термина work item наиболее интуитивен и наиболее популярен среди продвинутых в IT-технологиях Русскоязычных людей? Например среди программистов и других сотрудников IT-компаний.

Ближайшим переводом на мой (иностранный) взгляд является "задача". К сожалению в контексте термин work items используется как обобщающий для tasks, bug reports, suggestions и т.д., где tasks уже переводится как "задача". Получается конфликт например в предложении "Work items that are meant for internal purposes are called tasks."

Comment: Кроме «задача» есть ещё «задание».

Comment: Может быть "запись", например как запись в ежедневнике.

Comment: @YellowSky Спасибо за дополнение. К сожалению в данном контексте смысл "задания" слишком сильно подразумевает последующее решение. В то время как среди work items на многие типы не подразумевается решения, а на другие что-либо другое, напр Вопрос-Ответ

Comment: @DenisMakarenko Интересный нейтральный термин и подходит ко всем суб-типам work items. К сожалению "запись" может быть интерпретирована как и другой контекст, не связанный с работой. Напр. комментарий или запись в истории изменений.

Comment: Как насчет "поручение"?

Comment: @mustaccio "Поручение" обязательно (по крайней мере в моем понимании). А многие типы work items в данном контексте несут непринудительный характер. Напр. вопрос, предложение, запрос возможностей. Тем не менее спасибо за альтернативу.

Comment: просто "работа"

Comment: @w.hrybok См. пример предложения в комментарии под ответ от Dima

Comment: Отметь 3 работы как завершенные. Не вижу проблем во фразах втроде "три работы", "третья работа". Но немного двусмысленно может быть "эта работа".

Comment: Такие фразы грамматически некорректны. "работа" - несчетное существительное.

Comment: За последний год я сменил три работы. Это пример. Я не уверен, что это образец грамотности, но люди так говорят. Это нормальная фраза. Поэтому я не вижу ничего ненормального например во фразе: вчера я завершил три работы, которые мне направили из отдела рекламы.

Comment: Кроме того, в школе все мы выводили в тетрадках: классная работа и домашняя работа. Мне кажется, контекст очень близкий.

Comment: В чем-то вы все-таки правы. Явный пример. Работами так-же называются письменные отчеты, например результаты исследований. Среди нас есть знатоки? Совет бы не помешал...

Comment: Видимо комментарии, тем более спрятанные, далеко не все читают. Добавлю "работу" как ответ

Answer (score 5):

[Словарь](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=work%20item&l1=1) предлагает, в числе прочих, вариант `единица работы`. На мой взгляд, более внятно, чем `рабочий элемент`, который ассоциируется больше с (электро)техникой.

Comment: Близко, но не совсем то что надо. Единица работы близко по смыслу к "единица измерения работы". Что может вызывать ассоциации с например с рабочим временем или количеством работы. А здесь имеются ввиду самостоятельные, сформулированные задачи, рапорты об ошибках, предложения, запросы возможностей, вопросы. Которые требуют абсолютно разное кол-во усилий.

Comment: Там кстати есть еще вариант "отдельная работа", может быть не самый удобный для использования, но ИМХО самый корректный перевод

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft and several other companies translate it as *рабочий элемент* or *элемент работы*.

To me, the most intuitive translation would be *дело* (*сделал одно дело — берись за другое*).

Comment: Спасибо, встречал такой перевод, по-моему даже в продуктах Microsoft. Мне он показался рискованным и я хотел бы знать мнение большинства о его внятности. Вопрос всем: понятен ли лично вам термин "рабочий элемент" или "элемент работы"?

Comment: Мне непонятен, нет.

Comment: Мне тоже не понятен. «Единица работы» лучше.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, в контексте, где "термин work items используется как обобщающий для tasks, bug reports, suggestions и т.д", лучше всего подойдет "задание". У нас в компании "элементом работы" называют какую-то часть текущей задачи. Как это происходит в других компаниях - сказать не могу.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень важно слышать что используется на практике. Идет речь о крупной/ведущей компании?

Comment: В плане IT - скорее средняя.

Answer (score 2):

While “задача” is IMO the best translation for “work item,” the aforementioned by @YellowSky “задание” perfectly translates the term “task.”

Whether the whole text is under your control and you are free to choose terms from the scratch, I would stuck with:

- task ⇒ задание
- work item ⇒ задача

Comment: An open minded suggestion. In my view they're almost synonyms and can be easily confused with one another. But of course the opinion of the majority is what matters. Let's see what votes here will show over time. Thanks!

Comment: As you have noticed before, there is a slight difference (“задача” is something stated, while “задание” is more like being assigned.) The difference between “task“ and “work item” is not so crucial though. Issue-tracking s/w usually uses “assign tasks“ and “open issue/workitem” paradigm—that’s why I came with that suggestion.

Comment: You're correct on the meanings. I can see why you suggest this set up. And if I was the only end user, I would use it. My doubts are about end users that are not linguistic gurus and may miss the difference because it's not obvious enough to them.

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее интуитивным, на мой взгляд, будет "задача" или "задание". Да, это пересекается с задачей-таском, но за всю свою программистскую жизнь ни разу не слышал ни про "элемент работы", ни про "рабочий элемент". "Дело" тоже режет слух.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать просто "работа". Некоторые обсуждения этого варианта можно посмотреть в комментариях к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

"детали работы"

*Кто предпочитает такой вариант? Почему да/нет?*

> "Work items that are meant for internal purposes are called tasks." ->
>   Детали работы педназначенные для внутренних целей называются задачами.
>
> "Mark 3 work items as complete." -> Отметить 3 детали работы как
>   завершенные.

Comment: Please post it as an update to your original question, not an answer. It's OK to answer your own questions and mark your own answers as accepted, but the answer should be an answer, not another question. Thank you!

Comment: Лично у меня детали сразу ассоциируются с подробностями, например: вникнуть в детали работы.

Comment: Сейчас пришло в голову: в русском работа "штуками" не меряется. Это было приведено как недостаток к моему варианту, но кажется по этой же причине детали, элементы, единицы и т.п. неестественно выглядят в сочетании с работой в требуемом смысле

Comment: @Quassnoi This is an answer. It provides a translation for the original phrase, thus answering the original question. There are also two examples provided with this translation in practical use. I am asking for opinions of Russian speaking visitors in form of votes and comments, and I will only accept a suitable answer with highest amount of votes. Because I am not looking for a translation for myself, but for a broad audience.

Answer (score 0):

Это - просто фрагмент работы, - то есть, большое прозводственное задание (например, технологический цикл производства) как раз и состоит из отдельных фрагментов работы, которые планируются для исполнения (последовательного, параллельного и т.п.)

Comment: Ну это-то понятно, только как это сказать по-русски? Никто не говорит "фрагмент работы", кроме как в фразе типа "Фрагмент работы В.И.Ленина "Материализм и эмпириокритицизм".

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет "рабочий вопрос"? Мне это кажется неплохим вариантом.

Answer (score -1):

In that case Рабочая деятельность seems to be the closest translation

Comment: Предложение: "Mark 3 work items as complete." Перевод?